# will onActivityResult() restart my activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera

In my activity I am setting all the Views like ImageView, TextViews with theirs respective data using AsyncTask.

after `asyncTask.Execute();`

I have a `textView.onCLickListener` which calls Camera and after the picture is taken, the ImageView in the activity is set to this pic.

But the problem is my asyncTask is called again after the onActivityResult();

Here is my complete Activity code:

```
public class UserProfileActivity extends Activity {

//many instance fiels here
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.user_profile);

        new LongOperation().execute("");

        userImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName_profile);
        userLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userLocation_profile);
        editInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
        changeImage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changeImage_profile);
        userScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userScore_profile);
        friendsLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userFriends_profile);


            changeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
//Point 1
                }
            });
//Point 2
    }
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private InputStream is;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private String result;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

//Point 3
            try {
                HttpResponse response;

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://www.xxxxx.com/yyyy/zzzz");
                    //httpclient is global to maintain sessions
                    response = SignUpActivity.httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                    String line = "0";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error in reading input stream", e.toString());
                }
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
                    String status = jObj.getString("status");
                    score = jObj.getInt("credits");
                    level = jObj.getInt("level");
                    image = jObj.getString("image");
                    fname = jObj.getString("fname");
                    lname = jObj.getString("lname");
                    city = jObj.getString("city");
                    email = jObj.getString("email");
                    clickedUserId = jObj.getInt("user_id");

                    JSONArray friendsJsonArray = jObj.getJSONArray("friends");
                    size = friendsJsonArray.length();

                    ArrayList<String> friendsNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                    friendsIds = new int[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                        friendsNames.add(friendsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("name"));
                        friendsIds[i] = friendsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getInt("user_id");
                    }
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                            R.layout.simple_listview_item, friendsNames);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.d("error in creating json object", e.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
//Point 5
                Log.e("error main try", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }
            return "Executed";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            friendsList.setAdapter(adapter);
            userScore.setText(score + " points" + "   level " + level);
            userName.setText(fname + "  " + lname);
            userLocation.setText(city);
            changeImage.setText("Change image");
            editInfo.setText("Edit");
            friendsLabel.setText("Friends");
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(image).getContent());
                userImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
                userImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
            } catch (IOException e2) {

                e2.printStackTrace();
                userImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
            }

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

//Point 4
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {

                photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                userImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

            }else{

                Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfileActivity.this,
                        UserProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfileActivity.this,
                    UserProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you mean, if onCreate will be called, then no :)

Comment: Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: but my logcat shows LongOperation.execute(""); is called again. and this results in "SingleClientConnManager Exception: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated."

Comment: Maybe you are changing orientation as well ? That'd force onCreate to be called.

Comment: no. infact i handled orientation change for each activity in my manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera activity is meant to run in background.

Hence calling camera using the intent

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

will call the doInBackground(String... params)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're recreating the activity again by creating a new intent and starting the activity in the startActivityForResult logic (bottom part of your code)

Comment: but my code never reached any of the else blocks. I tested using logs

Comment: I'm sure it does. Debug your code with breakpoints and see why it happens

Comment: I'd test it again if I were you. Try debugging instead of logs, it's easier to see what is going on

Comment: In my edited question i named Point 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...this is where my code goes after clicking the TextView to call camera intent.

Comment: Please debug your code with breakpoints and see if you're right about not getting to the recreation of the activity... If you'd see it doesn't, let me know and I'll try to look at your code.

Comment: Did you debug your code and saw that the if is indeed satisfied?

Comment: yeah. If is satisfied. But the problem is before going to this if block, the AsyncTask is called again. please once check the edited questions. I wrote Point 1,2,3,4 and 5 . This is the sequence of my code flow. sad, Whole day i was trying to fix this :(

Comment: One thing i found out is that, startActivityForResult runs in background until i take a picture and press OK. Might these be a problem with this back ground process and the doInBackground of the asyncTask??

Comment: @IncrediApp: Yeah that is the problem. I checked with my simple and working app for camera intent. I just Added an asyncTask in the activity and override doInBackground. when camera intent is called and the camera is opened, that calls the doInBackground.

Comment: Great! Sorry I couldn't help more

Answer (score 1):

Its an issue of memory leak . Try using

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bmOptions.inSampleSize = 8;
```

As image taken from camera is produces huge sized bitmaps

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the activity again after receiving the picture. Thats why onCreate is called and the AsyncTask executes again.

Comment: but where am i calling the activity again??\